# Square Connect API V2: Partial updates to catalog objects?

Tags: square-connect

In the V2 api, is there a way to partially update a catalog object? For example, if I have an item, and I don't want to keep track of modifier_list_info, it seems I have to send that data with any upserts otherwise it will get wiped out.

Is there a way to specifiy a partial update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to update a catalog object would be to first retrieve the object (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievecatalogobject), and then edit the properties you need to change. For instance, the response will have an object field so

```
response.object.item_data.name = 'Food'
```

will change the name to 'Food'. Then pass the entire object back to the UpsertCatalogObject endpoint. This will keep all the same properties except for changing the name.